# SwiftUI TextField inside Stack locking up inaccessible

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

After quite some time troubleshooting (and stripping entire views to bare-bones into test file) for the cause of Textfields in a Stack o 'lock up', or not be accessible, I found that it's when some modifiers to the stack is present.
In this case it was because of a .Shadow

It is understood that some modifiers apply to each view within the modified view. But that should be cool.

Therefore I know the WHAT, but does anybody know the **WHY ?**

```
@State private var tempName: String = ""
@State private var tempSurname: String = ""
@State private var tempPhone: String = ""

var body: some View {

        VStack  { //Stack 1
            Text("Please provide your details")
                VStack (spacing: 16) {
                       #warning ("check out why below textfields wont accept interaction")
                            TextField("User Name", text: $tempName)
                            TextField("User Surname", text: $tempSurname)
                            TextField("User Phone", text: $tempPhone)
                  }
                  .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                  .padding(.vertical, 16)
                  .shadow(radius: 8, x: 2, y: 4)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is understood that some modifiers apply to each view within the modified view

That's true.

However, you can use [`compositingGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/compositinggroup()) to apply the modifier to the **outermost view only**:

```
VStack(spacing: 16) {
    // ...
}
.padding(.horizontal, 8)
.padding(.vertical, 16)
.compositingGroup() // add before `shadow`
.shadow(radius: 8, x: 2, y: 4)
```

---

Here is a very good explanation taken directly from the documentation:

```
/// Wraps this view in a compositing group.
///
/// A compositing group makes compositing effects in this view's ancestor
/// views, such as opacity and the blend mode, take effect before this view
/// is rendered.
///
/// Use `compositingGroup()` to apply effects to a parent view before
/// applying effects to this view.
///
/// In the example below the `compositingGroup()` modifier separates the
/// application of effects into stages. It applies the ``View/opacity(_:)``
/// effect to the VStack before the `blur(radius:)` effect is applied to the
/// views inside the enclosed ``ZStack``. This limits the scope of the
/// opacity change to the outermost view.
///
///     VStack {
///         ZStack {
///             Text("CompositingGroup")
///                 .foregroundColor(.black)
///                 .padding(20)
///                 .background(Color.red)
///             Text("CompositingGroup")
///                 .blur(radius: 2)
///         }
///         .font(.largeTitle)
///         .compositingGroup()
///         .opacity(0.9)
///     }
///
/// ![A view showing the effect of the compositingGroup modifier in applying
/// compositing effects to parent views before child views are
/// rendered.](SwiftUI-View-compositingGroup.png)
///
/// - Returns: A view that wraps this view in a compositing group.
@inlinable public func compositingGroup() -> some View
```

Comment: Thank you. 
That's exactly the issue, and the explanation provides the insight that I needed for this.

Comment: Don't just feel that it's the right answer. ;-D From the documentation, it is the definitive answer